# Spring Security anyRequest.authenticated behavior

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i am trying to implement a simple Spring security project but I am facing an issue where the behavior of `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();` is not understandable. what i expect from this method is to prevent all incoming requests until the user is authenticated but in my case all the requests are go through and no interception happened. the normal behavior of preventing request to go through took a place when  I un-comment the lines which include hasAnyAuthority.

Below is My security configs

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CustomAuthFilter customAuthFilter = new CustomAuthFilter(authenticationManagerBean());
       //override behavior of url for our api

        customAuthFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/login/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll();
        /////http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(GET,"/api/users/").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        //////http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(POST,"/api/user/save/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN");

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(customAuthFilter);
        http.addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthorizationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your `CustomAuthFilter` implementation? Also, share which endpoint you are requesting.

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved the issue , it was just a miss-understanding of how authenticated method works.

so first Spring security checks if the user authenticated and and then checks if this endpoint need any type of authorization. if authenticated and not authorization exist the user would be redirected to the endpoint. it make sense for me now.

Thank you.